# PGraphics2D should implement cloneable but throws exception

Tags: java, processing, cloning

Using Java Processing, I'm trying to make a deep copy of a PGraphics2D object

```
PGraphics2D pg_render;
pg_render = (PGraphics2D) createGraphics(width, height, P2D);
PGraphics2D pg_postprocd = (PGraphics2D)pg_render.clone();
```

Which throws a CloneNotSupportedException :

> Unhandled exception type CloneNotSupportedException

Yet reading [the doc](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/opengl/PGraphics2D.html) it seems like cloning is implemented.

I need to have two instances of the PGraphics2D objects so that I can apply post-processing effects on one and keep the other one clean for analysing motion vectors and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Exception

The `PGraphics` class does not itself implement `Clonable`. Rather, it extends `PImage` and this is the class that actually implements the `Cloneable` interface.

This is why your call to `pg_render.clone()` throws `CloneNotSupportedException`, since PGraphics doesn't actually support cloning (but happens to extend a class that does).

### Solution

The static method below returns a *clone* of the input PGraphics object. It makes a new `PGraphics` object with `createGraphics()`, clones the style (style includes things like current fill colour), and finally clones the pixel buffer.

#### Code

```
static PGraphics clonePGraphics(PGraphics source) {

  final String renderer;
  switch (source.parent.sketchRenderer()) {
    case "processing.opengl.PGraphics2D" :
      renderer = PConstants.P2D;
      break;
    case "processing.opengl.PGraphics3D" :
      renderer = PConstants.P3D;
      break;
    default : // secondary sketches cannot use FX2D
      renderer = PConstants.JAVA2D;
  }

  PGraphics clone = source.parent.createGraphics(source.width, source.height, renderer);
  
  clone.beginDraw();
  clone.style(source.getStyle()); // copy style (fillColor, etc.)
  source.loadPixels(); // graphics buffer -> int[] buffer
  clone.pixels = source.pixels.clone(); // in's int[] buffer -> clone's int[] buffer
  clone.updatePixels(); // int[] buffer -> graphics buffer
  clone.endDraw();
  
  return clone;
}
```